# How to call method when UILocalNotification is fired in SWIFT?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uilocalnotification

I have a local notification and need to call method when user is notified. How to achieve that?

Comment: Before downvoting give some reasons in comments

Comment: Need to show code here for Understand your problem.

Comment: I am not asking its implementation I just need an idea to realize that

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [this](https://github.com/AhmettKeskin/LocalNotificationHelper) library for easier handling for `UILocalNotifications`. Using this you can easily handle all actions. And to answer your question you can achieve it like this:

```
LocalNotificationHelper.sharedInstance().registerUserNotificationWithActionButtons(actions: actions)
```

But you gotta handle it from within `appDelegate`.